# How to access Youtube_it ruby query results?

Tags: ruby, xml, youtube

I am trying to implement the [youtube_it](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) youtube api wrapper for ruby and have it working except I'm stumped as to how the query results should be accessed.

Here is my query:

```
client.videos_by(:query => "penguin", :max_results => 1)
Submitting request [url=http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=1&start-index=1&vq=penguin].
=> #<YouTubeIt::Response::VideoSearch:0xb6c41b14 @feed_id="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos", @updated_at=Wed Nov 03 18:01:39 UTC 2010, @videos=[#<YouTubeIt::Model::Video:0xb6c424d8 @thumbnails=[#<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0xb6c6b694 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oSbLpQEZP1Y/2.jpg", @width=120, @height=90, @time="00:01:34">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0xb6c6b248 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oSbLpQEZP1Y/1.jpg", @width=120, @height=90, @time="00:00:47">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0xb6c6a988 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oSbLpQEZP1Y/3.jpg", @width=120, @height=90, @time="00:02:21">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0xb6c69e34 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oSbLpQEZP1Y/0.jpg", @width=320, @height=240, @time="00:01:34">], @categories=[#<YouTubeIt::Model::Category:0xb6ca5d6c @term="Music", @label="Music">], @noembed=false, @racy=false, @favorite_count=7862, @duration=188, @author=#<YouTubeIt::Model::Author:0xb6c9942c @name="wili", @uri="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/wili">, @updated_at=Tue Nov 02 08:45:25 UTC 2010, @longitude=nil, @position=nil, @view_count=1682350, @html_content="penguin", @media_content=[#<YouTubeIt::Model::Content:0xb6c770d4 @url="http://www.youtube.com/v/oSbLpQEZP1Y?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata", @duration=188, @format=#<YouTubeIt::Model::Video::Format:0xb656d108 @name=:swf, @format_code=5>, @default=true, @mime_type="application/x-shockwave-flash">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Content:0xb6c766d4 @url="rtsp://v5.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlWPxkBpcsmoRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp", @duration=188, @format=#<YouTubeIt::Model::Video::Format:0xb656d11c @name=:rtsp, @format_code=1>, @default=false, @mime_type="video/3gpp">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Content:0xb6c75d38 @url="rtsp://v8.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlWPxkBpcsmoRMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp", @duration=188, @format=#<YouTubeIt::Model::Video::Format:0xb656d0f4 @name=:three_gpp, @format_code=6>, @default=false, @mime_type="video/3gpp">], @description="penguin", @latitude=nil, @title="penguin", @published_at=Mon May 08 18:11:01 UTC 2006, @player_url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSbLpQEZP1Y&feature=youtube_gdata_player", @rating=#<YouTubeIt::Model::Rating:0xb6c5eb4c @min=1, @max=5, @average=4.676985, @rater_count=2746>, @keywords=["pigloo", "penguin"], @video_id="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oSbLpQEZP1Y", @where=nil>], @total_result_count=291282, @offset=1, @max_result_count=1>
```

I would like to retrieve the URL and thumbnail links. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a great deal of knowledge of this particular gem, but your answer should at least be close to this. You can access the object directly through the `videos` accessor, which will give you the video object, on which `thumbnails` each have a `url`. so you could do the following:

```
reply = client.videos_by(:query => "penguin", :max_results => 1)
reply.videos.first.thumbnails.first.url # the thumbnail for the first video
reply.videos.first.player_url # The website for the video
reply.videos.first.media_content.first.url # direct embed url
```

It might be useful to search for some ruby beginners guides to help catch you up to speed as well. Good luck!

Comment: You rock. I couldn't figure which methods to call on reply, using your example, but reply.videos.first works like a champ. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

william's answer is correct, when you do it

```
client.videos_by(:query => "penguin", :max_results => 1)
```

this return an array called videos, so you just need iterate it

```
client.videos.each do |video|
  video.title
  video.thumbnails
  video.video_id
end
```

good luck!